# Can I upload a youtube video using the youtube api without a gui?

Tags: http, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am trying to automate video upload to YouTube without me needing to click a web-browser to authorize the upload every time.

[image]

When I go to the Youtube API console to setup some credentials, presumably with "User Data" because I assume that is what you need to upload, it gives the following warning:

[image]

Does this mean that there is no way to automate uploading videos from a console application, and that every upload will require me to click from a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first screen you are looking at is the Oauth2 authorization screen.   In order to access private user data you must have access to that data.   Oauth2 gives you that option by asking the user can I access your data?

The fact that you want to upload to data you own would normally lead me to say you should use a service account.   Service accounts are preauthorized.  I could take the service account email address and grant it access to a folder on my google drive and then it would be able to read and write from that folder.

This is not an option with YouTube.  The YouTube api does not support service accounts.

You will need to authenticate your code yourself once save the refresh token then use that in your console application to request an new access token and upload the video.

Answer: With the YouTube API there is no way around the authorization form you have to authenticate it.

Comment: Great answer. I have my program to the point where it launches a web ui, and you have to click in order to start the upload. In Qt/C++, should this be easy enough to automate inside the console without having to launch a browser or gui?

Comment: No a user will have to authenticate it first.   Then you save the refresh token you will be able to use the refresh token in your console application.   There is no way to automate the authentication.    Once you have the refresh token you will be able to upload to that account all you want.

Comment: Okay, so if I can make my QNetworkAccessManager login to an account that is authenticated, it will be able to upload without the prompt? Up until now, I have needed to authenticate my upload every single time.

Comment: sorry i have no experience with QNetworkAccessManager  you should ask another question about that, as its probably a separate issue / question.